# cPanel - Redirect written in .htaccess does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The following scripts in .htaccess works properly on localhost, but not work after I uploading the website to server. For example, "http://ipaddress/mywebsite/api/" will redirect me to api.php located in mywebsite directory.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^api/^ api.php

</IfModule>
```

File Hierarchy

```
root of apache
+--mywebsite
   +--.htaccess
   +--index.php
   +--api.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule you have used is invalid, due to the ending `^`. Use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^api/?$ api.php
```

Note that the question mark makes the trailing slash optional. If you want to only rewrite when the slash is present, then remove the question mark.

I would also recommend adding the `L` flag to the rule, in case you add other rules later on:

```
RewriteRule ^api/?$ api.php [L]
```

**Update:** Per your comment, change the rule to the following to allow `api/*` to be passed to `api.php` as well:

```
RewriteRule ^api api.php [L]
```

This will pass `api`, `api/`, and `api/<anything>` to `api.php`. You can retrieve the request by fetching the URI with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your correction of my wrong rewrite rule. Your recommendation works properly on localhost, but still not in the remote server. It still return error code 404 and redirect me to the default 403 error page, which is the provided by the hosting service provider.

Comment: Please ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your server configuration and that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in your virtual host config. If you are on shared hosting, you will need to ask your host if it is enabled. Alternatively, you can add random text to the top of your `.htaccess` file. If you receive an Internal Server Error, then you know that these are enabled. If it is, then we can take it from there...

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I discovered that my problem does not relate to mod_rewrite, which is enabled in my server. For example, "http://ipaddress/mywebsite/api/" properly redirect me to api.php. However, if one more part is added to it, "http://ipaddress/mywebsite/api/new", the problem occurs and it redirect me to the default error page. I cannot figure out the reason.